# multiple marker on MapMyIndia in React Js

Tags: reactjs, marker, mapmyindia-api

I am trying to show multiple markers on MapMyIndia in React,
I used `mapmyindia-react` package.

```
  <div className="w-100 overflow-hidden">
      <Maps
        markers={[
          {
            position: [21.145664, 72.759782],

            draggable: true,
            title: "Marker title",
            onClick: (e) => {
              console.log("clicked ");
            },
            onDragend: (e) => {
              console.log("dragged");
            },
          },
        ]}
      />
    </div>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
  markers={[
    {
        position: [18.5314, 73.845],
        draggable: true,
        title: "Marker 1"
    },
    {
        position: [18.5414, 73.845],
        draggable: true,
        title: "Marker 2"
    }
  ]}
```